# Knockout mapping selected values between two arrays

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I need to show on UI all checkboxes from independed JSON array (lstRoles) and map selected checkboxes as result array to property roles in result JSON object (tObj). 
But I don't know how to do it in right wat (I just start learning Knockout). How initialize checkboxes in case result JSON object allready have some data.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>

 <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'choiceTmpl', foreach: lstRoles },click: myFunction.bind($data)"></ul>

<ul data-bind="foreach: lstRoles">
    <li>
        Name at position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"> </span>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data },click: myFunction.bind($data) " />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr />

<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel)"></div>

<script id="choiceTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data } " />
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
    </li>
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

var tObj = {"name":"John", "roles":[{id:1, name:"Role1", desc:"Desc1"},{id:2, name:"Role2", desc:"Desc2"}]};
var lstRoles=[{id:1, name:"Role1", desc:"Desc1"},{id:2, name:"Role2", desc:"Desc2"},{id:2, name:"Role3", desc:"Desc3"},{id:2, name:"Role4", desc:"Desc4"}];

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tObj);
viewModel.alldata = lstRoles;
ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
    function myFunction(data)
    {
       viewModel.roles.push(data);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but your viewmodel and bindings look totally out of place. you are binding to viewModel, lstRoles is not defined in the view model. myFunction is outside your viewModel, you cannot call that. Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/jEyb9/

Comment: Thanks. I have added updated code as answer, I would be grate to get feedback from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code and I got a behavior that I need.
But I am not sure that way is 100% right.
You are welcome with any comments.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>

<div data-bind="foreach: alldata">    
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, click: function(data, event) { return myFunction1(data, event); }, checked: $data.rc" />          
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"> </span>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.desc"> </span></br>

</div>

<hr />

Count Select Roles : <span data-bind="text: roles().length"> </span><br/>

<div data-bind="foreach: roles">    
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data },click: function(data, event) { return myFunction1(data, event); }, checked: $data.rc" />          
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"> </span>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.desc"> </span></br>

</div>

<hr />

<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel)"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var tObj = {"name":"John", "roles":[]};
var lstRoles=[{id:1, name:"Role1", desc:"Desc1", rc:true, ds:true},{id:2, name:"Role2", desc:"Desc2", rc:false, ds:false},{id:3, name:"Role3", desc:"Desc3",rc:true, ds:false},{id:4, name:"Role4", desc:"Desc4", rc:false, ds:true}];

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tObj);
viewModel.alldata = ko.observableArray(lstRoles);

viewModel.initRoles = function()
{
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.alldata(), function(item){
      if (item.rc)
        {
        viewModel.roles.push(item);
        }
    });
};

viewModel.initRoles();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
    function myFunction(data)
    {
       viewModel.roles.push(data);
       return true;
    }

 function myFunction1(data, event)
    {
      if ($(event.toElement).is(':checked'))
       {    
          viewModel.roles.push(data);
       }    
    else
    {
       viewModel.roles.remove(function(item)
            {                
        return (item.id == data.id);
        });
    }

       return true;
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: myFunction and myFunction1 must belong to the viewmodel you are binding to. Tell us what is it that you are exactly looking for. In terms of requirements and may be we can help.

Comment: Hi I need to create list of checkboxed based on lstRoles arrays and all cheched values copy to  tObj.roles array. I hope it is short description is good for you.